# Atomic W*-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am looking for any information concerning atomic W*-algebras.

Def. A W*-algebra $M$ is called atomic if for any projection $p$ in $M$ there is a 
minimal projection $e\in M$ with $e\leq p$.

Q. Is there any characterization for atomic W*-algebras?

Let me say what I know about. Let Min$(M)$ be the set of all minimal projections in $M$. For a given  minimal projection $e$ in $M$, let $z(e)$ be the central carrier (central support) of $e$ ($z(e)$  is minimal among all central projections).  The W*-algebra $z(e)M$ is a factor and $M=\bigoplus_{e\in Min(M)} z(e)M$. To sum up with, any characterization of atomic+factor W*-algebras is concerned. Any reference or direct proof is appreciated.

Comment: For example, $M$ is atomic if and only if $M_*$ has the Radon-Nikodym property. There are plenty of such characterisations, I believe you should make your question a bit more specific.

Comment: You are right. frankly I am  reading an old article entitled "Non commutative topology by Kummer "  in which  (factor) atomic W*-algebras are considered. I would like to know how much  we now know about these structures. For examples how much different examples (except of $B(H)$'s) exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An atomic factor is necessarily $B(H)$.

Because of the lack of central projections, a factor is of a definite type. Because it has a minimal projection, it has to be type I.